# Dynamically formed Anchor tag not invoking the click function

Tags: jquery

I have a cshtml

```
<td id="device-body">
    <ul>
        <li id="devicesInOffice"></li>
    </ul>
</td>
```

and i am trying to dynamically populate the li tag with a list of anchor tags(like below)

```
function populateDevicesAvailable(deviceType) {  
    if (deviceType.id != "") {  
        $.post(window.getOfficesDevicesUrl, { devicetypeId: deviceType.id },   
         function (results) {  
            var items = "";  
            $.each(results, function (i, device) {
                items += 
"<a id='" + device.Id + "' href= '" + "#" + "'    
                class='devices'     
                onclick='javascript:populateDeviceInfo()'>" + device.Name + "</a>";  
            });

            $("li#devicesInOffice").append(items);

        });
    }
    else {
        $("li#devicesInOffice").html("");
    }
};  


function populateDeviceInfo() {
}
```

The populateDeviceInfo function never gets called.I only get an error "object expected" when i click the hyperlink.

I also tried other ways(below) to call the function but nothing works.

```
$(".devices").click(function () {
    populateDeviceInfo();
});

 $("li#devicesInOffice a").click(function () {
    populateDeviceInfo();
```

Can somebody help me to find a way to call the function.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `live`, whenever you insert elements to the DOM dynamically event handlers do not get attached to then automatically

```
$(".devices").live('click', function () {
    populateDeviceInfo();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's right, links that are added after the handler has been registered will be not affected. That's why there's [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) methods for jQuery.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MHKhE/)**.

Comment: @Laven, if my answer is correct, please approve it as correct answer (click the hollow **V** under the number).

Answer (score 0):

If an element is dynamically generated, then the `click` function will not affect it, because `click` only binds to elements that already exist. You need to use the [`live`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function instead:

```
$(".devices, li#devicesInOffice a").live("click", function() {
  populateDeviceInfo();
}
```

You'll notice that you can use multiple jQuery selectors at once. This way, you don't have to repeat your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`delegate()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method to assign the handler to the container that holds your `.devices` elements.

```
$(function() {
    $('#devicesInOffice').delegate('.devices','click', populateDeviceInfo);
});
```

This places a single handler on the `#devicesInOffice` element (as long as it was present when the page loaded).

That handler is invoked when a click occurs on any nested element that matches the `.devices` selector.